# Check how many words from a given list occur in list of text/strings

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, text

I have a list of text data which contains reviews, something likes this:

```
1. 'I have bought several of the Vitality canned dog food products and have found them all to be of good quality. The product looks more like a stew than a processed meat and it smells better. My Labrador is finicky and she appreciates this product better than  most.'

2. 'Product arrived labeled as Jumbo Salted Peanuts...the peanuts were actually small sized unsalted. Not sure if this was an error or if the vendor intended to represent the product as "Jumbo".',

3. 'This is a confection that has been around a few centuries.  It is a light, pillowy citrus gelatin with nuts - in this case Filberts. And it is cut into tiny squares and then liberally coated with powdered sugar.  And it is a tiny mouthful of heaven.  Not too chewy, and very flavorful.  I highly recommend this yummy treat.  If you are familiar with the story of C.S. Lewis\' "The Lion, The Witch, and The Wardrobe" - this is the treat that seduces Edmund into selling out his Brother and Sisters to the Witch.
```

I have a seperate list of words which I want to know exists in the these reviews:

```
['food','science','good','buy','feedback'....]
```

I want to know which of these words are present in the review and select reviews which contains certain number of these words. For example, lets say only select reviews which contains atleast 3 of the words from this list, so it displays all those reviews, but also show which of those were encountered in the review while selecting it.

I have the code for selecting reviews containing at least **3 of the words, but how do I get the second part which tells me which words exactly were encountered**. Here is my initial code:

```
keywords = list(words)
text = list(df.summary.values)
sentences=[]
for element in text:
    if len(set(keywords)&set(element.split(' '))) >=3:
        sentences.append(element)
```

Comment: You can hold it as a list of tuples, containing the reviews and the words that were encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the second part, allow me to revisit how to approach the first part. A handy approach here is to cast your review strings into sets of word strings.

Like this:

```
review_1 = "I have bought several of the Vitality canned dog food products and"
review_1 = set(review_1.split(" "))
```

Now the review_1 set contains one of every word. Then take your list of words, convert it to a set, and do an intersection.

```
words = ['food','science','good','buy','feedback'....]
words = set(['food','science','good','buy','feedback'....])

matches = review_1.intersection(words)
```

The resulting set, matches, contains all the words that are common. The length of this is the number of matches.

Now, this does not work if you cared about how many of each word matches. For example, if the word "food" is found twice in the review and "science" is found once, does that count as matching three words?

If so, let me know via comment and I can write some code to update the answer to include that scenario.

### EDIT: Updating to include comment question

---

If you want to keep a count of how many times each word repeats, then hang onto the review list. Only cast it to set when performing the intersection. Then, use the 'count' list method to count the number of times each match appears in the review. In the example below, I use a dictionary to store the results.

```
review_1 = "I have bought several of the Vitality canned dog food products and"

words = ['food','science','good','buy','feedback'....]
words = set(['food','science','good','buy','feedback'....])

matches = set(review_1).intersection(words)

match_counts = dict()
for match in matches:
    match_counts[match] = words.count(match)
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you. Although, if we convert it into set, we wont be able to find out how many times that words occurred. Any thoughts on that ?

Comment: Perfect! This is great!

Comment: Did you actually run the second snippet? It's full of errors. First of all, you forgot to split review_1. Second, why are you making words a set? You're writing words = [...] then writing words = set([...]) thus overwriting whatever you wrote in the last line. For the later part of your code to work, the line words.count(match) will throw an error since you made words a set. I suggest you completely remove the line words = set([...]); intersection will still work with word as a list.

Comment: You're also splitting review1 in the first part with review1.split(" "). What if instead of the part "dog food  products" you have something like "dog food, products" or "dog food; products"? It'll fail completely, as the code doesn't account for punctuation. I suggest you look into re.

Answer (score 0):

You can use set intersection for finding the common words:

```
def filter_reviews(data, *, trigger_words = frozenset({'food', 'science', 'good', 'buy', 'feedback'})):
    for review in data:
        words = review.split()  # use whatever method is appropriate to get the words
        common = trigger_words.intersection(words)
        if len(common) >= 3:
            yield review, common
```